# How to replace \ with . in java String

Tags: java

I want to replace `\` with `.` in `String` java.

Example `src\main\java\com\myapp\AppJobExecutionListener`

Here I want to get like `src.main.java.com.myapp.AppJobExecutionListener`

I tried `str.replaceAll("\\","[.]")` and `str.replaceAll("\\","[.]")` but it is not working.

I am still getting original string `src\main\java\com\myapp\AppJobExecutionListener`

Comment: Did you reassign the result to `str`?  ie `str = str.replaceAll(...)`

Comment: `"src\main\java\com\vxl\appanalytix\AppJobExecutionListener"` as a string is invalid in java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String is immutable in Java, so whatever methods you invoke on the String object are not reflected on it unless you reassign it.

```
String s = "ABC";
s.replaceAll("B","D");
System.out.println(s); //still prints "ABC"
s = s.replaceAll("B","D");
System.out.println(s); //prints "ADC"
```

Comment: I got it with two steps. a)String str1=str.replaceAll("\\","\\\\"). b)a)String str1=str.replaceAll("\\","[.]").step a) is importent before go for step b).

Comment: @user2215139 it's good that you understood it and solved it with less code, keep it up!

Answer (score 1):

Assign it back to string str variable, .[String#replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) doesn't changes the string itself, it returns a new String.

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\\\",".")
```

Comment: Ya I tried this but why three slashes \\\? I am getting compilation problem I tried for str = str.replaceAll("\\",".") but still exception  like java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
 ^

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
String original = "Some text with \\ and rest of the text";
String replaced = original.replace("\\",".");

System.out.println(replaced);
```

Comment: \ is escape character. Are u sure that this will run perfectly?

Answer (score 1):

**'\'** character is doubled in a string like **'\\'**. So **'\\'** character should be used to replace it with '.' character and also using **`replace`** instead of **`replaceAll`** would be enough to make it. Here is a sample;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString = "src\\main\\java\\com\\vxl\\appanalytix\\AppJobExecutionListener";
    System.out.println("Before Replaced: " + myString);
    myString = myString.replace("\\", ".");
    System.out.println("After Replaced: " + myString);
}
```

This will give you:

```
Before Replaced: src\main\java\com\vxl\appanalytix\AppJobExecutionListener
After Replaced: src.main.java.com.vxl.appanalytix.AppJobExecutionListener
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\\\", ".");
```

With [`String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29):

```
str = str.replace('\\', '.');
```

With [`String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
str = str.replace("\\", ".");
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're using `replaceAll`, which takes regular expression patterns. That makes life much more complicated than it needs to be. Unless you're *trying* to use regular expressions, just use `String.replace` instead.

In fact, as you're only replacing one *character* with another, you can just use character literals:

```
String replaced = original.replace('\\', '.');
```

The `\` is doubled as it's the escape character in Java character literals - but as the above *doesn't* use regular expressions, the period has no special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

String replaced = original.replace('\', '.');

try this its works well

Answer (score 0):

Use **replace** instead of **replaceall**

```
String my_str="src\\main\\java\\com\\vxl\\appanalytix\\AppJobExecutionListener";
String my_new_str = my_str.replace("\\", ".");
System.out.println(my_new_str);
```

**[DEMO AT IDEONE.COM](http://ideone.com/88r3JT)**

Answer (score 0):

replaceAll takes a regex as the first parameter.

To replace the \ you need to double escape. You need an additional \ to escape the first . And as it is a regex input you need to escape those again. As other answers have said string is immutable so you will need to assign the result

```
 String newStr = str.replaceAll("\\\\", ".");
```

The second parameter is not regex so you can just put . in there but note you need four slashes to replace one backslash if using replaceAll

Answer (score 0):

i tried this:

```
String s="src\\main\\java\\com\\vxl\\appanalytix\\AppJobExecutionListener";
    s = s.replace("\\", ".");
    System.out.println("s: "+ s);
```

output: src.main.java.com.vxl.appanalytix.AppJobExecutionListener

Answer (score -1):

Just change the line to

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\",".");
```

Edit : I didnt try it, because the problem here is not whether its a correct regex,but the problem here is that he is not assigning the str to new str value. Anyways regex corrected now.

Comment: have you tried it? `replaceAll` doesn't take second argument as regex, its just a string. So it should be . not [.]

Comment: No , i didnt try it, because the problem here is not whether its a correct regex,but the problem here is that he is not assigning the str to new str value.